ExecuteNonQuery() and DA.Update()
I have been trying to insert data from a Data Table into a SQL Server table.
This is the code I'm using for this part:
Public conn As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-C1JI0OA\SQLEXPRESS; TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=true; TrustServerCertificate=true; Trusted_Connection=True; Database = Fingerprint reader;")
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt1)
da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "dbo.fingerprintslogs")
ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Table"

conn.Open()
For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

    EmployeeID = row(0)
    Weekday1 = row(1)
    FirstCheckIn = row(2)
    LastCheckout = row(3)

    Using command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fingerprintslogs (EmployeeID, WeekDay,FirstCheckIn,LastCheckOut ) VALUES (@EmployeeID, @WeekDay, @FirstCheckIn, @LastCheckOut)", conn), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
        With command.Parameters
            .Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0)
            .Add("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
            .Add("@FirstCheckIn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0)
            .Add("@LastCheckOut", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0)
        End With
        command.Parameters("@EmployeeID").Value = EmployeeID
        command.Parameters("@WeekDay").Value = Weekday1
        command.Parameters("@FirstCheckIn").Value = FirstCheckIn
        command.Parameters("@LastCheckOut").Value = LastCheckout
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
Next
 conn.Close()

Users in previous questions here1 here2 here3  had recommended using a Data Adapter.Update() to insert the data into the SQL DB, when I used .Update on this code (as shown below):
Public conn As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-C1JI0OA\SQLEXPRESS; TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=true; TrustServerCertificate=true; Trusted_Connection=True; Database = Fingerprint reader;")
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt1)
    da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "dbo.fingerprintslogs")
    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Table"
    
    conn.Open()
    For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

        EmployeeID = row(0)
        Weekday1 = row(1)
        FirstCheckIn = row(2)
        LastCheckout = row(3)

        Using command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Fingerprintslogs (EmployeeID, WeekDay,FirstCheckIn,LastCheckOut ) VALUES (@EmployeeID, @WeekDay, @FirstCheckIn, @LastCheckOut)", conn), adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
            With command.Parameters
                .Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0)
                .Add("@WeekDay", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
                .Add("@FirstCheckIn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0)
                .Add("@LastCheckOut", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0)
            End With
            command.Parameters("@EmployeeID").Value = EmployeeID
            command.Parameters("@WeekDay").Value = Weekday1
            command.Parameters("@FirstCheckIn").Value = FirstCheckIn
            command.Parameters("@LastCheckOut").Value = LastCheckout
            adapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))

        End Using    
    Next
     conn.Close()

I had the first column of data (sample of data shown after this) repeated 1620 times, (which is actually the total number of rows I have in the data table), but when using  command.ExecuteNonQuery() the data were inserted correctly into the DB. I just noticed that it is slightly "Not ordered" I would say, but that is not a big of a problem I guess?



Employee   ID
Weekday
FirstCheckIn
LastCheckOut




10
Monday
04/15/2024   0:00:00
04/15/2024   15:04:00


10
Tuesday
04/16/2024   8:46:00
04/16/2024   14:41:00


10
Wednesday
04/17/2024   8:34:00
04/17/2024   0:00:00


10
Thursday
04/18/2024   7:50:00
04/18/2024   15:18:00


10
Saturday
04/20/2024   9:00:00
04/20/2024   15:10:00


10
Sunday
04/21/2024   8:16:00
04/21/2024   15:53:00


10
Monday
04/22/2024   8:41:00
04/22/2024   15:22:00



My question is: why did this happen? And would using command.ExecuteNonQuery() cause any troubles? Or in other terms: what is the reason of the different results between the two scenarios?

If it doesn't work then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, we can't see what you did wrong. The code you posted is a mess and pretty much works by accident, so I don't imagine the code that actually uses the data adapter is any better. Read this and then provide such an example for your issue. Showing us code that works but doesn't do what you are trying to do doesn't help us help you do it.

What actually is your question? Does the code you show work or not?

See here for an example I wrote years ago for saving data from a DataTable using a data adapter. Follow what I actually do there first, then post back if you have any remaining issues. If you do need more help, show us a minimal code example that shows the actual issue.

@DaleK , As i mentioned in the actual post  (My question is, why did this happen? and would using command.ExecuteNonQuery() cause any troubles?) , and yes this code works . it doesn't work when i change the command.excutenonQuery() to adapter.Update(ds.Tables(0)) and instead i get the first row of data repeated over and over in the DB .


if you have working code then why do you wish to change it? 2) if you want to know why your other code isn't working, show that code, not the working code.


that it is slightly "Not ordered" - relational databases are generally unordered sets of data. You have no guarantee of any ordering, unless you explicitly specify an ORDER BY in your SELECT clauses to retrieve the data

@DaleK i edited the post for more clarification .

@marc_s understood , thnx

@jmcilhinney i never said anything doesn't work , i edited the post for more clarification. thank you .

@jmcilhinney My question was stated at the end of the post , i don't really understand the reason you that gets you tempered .
And it is true , i said that something " didn't work" in an earlier comment a day/days ago , which was in a completely different thing of what i am asking about in this question, i clarified what happened exactly in each senario .
and if you feel that i'm wasting your time you can just ignore my questions , thanks for the earlier answers anyway , good luck ! .

If you use an adapter to update the database then you don't need to put it inside a loop and specify the command or the parameters. It just needs a table with a primary key defined then it figures out what to update. It looks at the datatable passed to the Update method and decides what rows needed to be updated using the RowState property of the row.

There are easier ways to do database than this. Are you using .net or .net framework?

Can you see why I said using a DataTable is an extra complication? When you have the data from an Excel row, send it to the database. Simple.

Actually, you don't show where dt1 comes from. But, I see VERY little reason to THEN create a whole new dataset, when in fact you have a perfectly fine and working and built table for this purpose. In other words, why bother creating a dataset which is a collection of tables when in fact you don't have nor need a collection of tables. In other words, I see little reason here to create + use a dataset - it's simply not required. And if the columns in dt1 are the same name, then you don't even need a loop.

See my post below on how you can set the existing table to the database.

I see little reason to create + use a dataset here. A dataset is a "collection" of tables, and you don't have nor need such a collection of tables.
If the column names in dt1 are the same, then you can use that to update the data base.
Hence this:
    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT EmployeeID, WeekDay, FirstCheckIn, LastCheckOut FROM Fingerprintslogs "

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim daupdate As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim cmdBuild As New SqlCommandBuilder(daupdate)
            daupdate.Update(dt1)

        End Using
    End Using

And even your existing code never needed to use some dataset anyway, but if column names match up, then above should work, and work without any looping.
